# Check the current shell and update user profiles using shell script

Tags: shell

I want to write shell script to update user profiles like `.zshrc`, `.bashrc` based on which shell is currently used. What's the best way to determine the file path? I need to do two things,

1. Determine which shell is currently used
2. Know the path of user profiles

I can achieve it like below, but looks odd.

```
if [ "/usr/bin/zsh" == "$SHELL" ]; then
  PROFILE_NAME=.zshrc
elif [ "/usr/bin/bash" == "$SHELL" ]; then
  PROFILE_NAME=.bashrc
fi

PROFILE_PATH=$HOME/$PROFILE_NAME
echo $PROFILE_PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks reasonable.  There is no standard way to ask a generic POSIX shell to tell you what its configuration file is.  And there isn't always just one!  For example in Bash you might be looking for `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.  If one exists and not the other, you probably want to modify the existing one.

By the way, most users will not expect a program to modify their shell configuration automatically.  Most programs just print a message to the screen to the effect of:

```
If you want to use these settings, please add them to your shell profile:

    export PATH=...
    export STUFF=...
```